# jQuery function stops when browser zooms out

Tags: jquery, scroller, window-resize, zooming

I'm using SmoothDivScroll 1.1 and everything is working fine till I zoom out in a browser (firefox, chrome and safari tested on windows 7) (when zoomed in the scroller doesn't stop). The way SmoothDivScroll is loaded is:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$("div#projectenRijEen").smoothDivScroll({}); 
$("div#projectenRijTwee").smoothDivScroll({});
$("div#projectenRijDrie").smoothDivScroll({});
$("div#projectenRijEen").bind("mouseover",function(){$(this).smoothDivScroll("stopAutoScroll")}).bind("mouseout",function(){$(this).smoothDivScroll("startAutoScroll")});
$("div#projectenRijTwee").bind("mouseover",function(){$(this).smoothDivScroll("stopAutoScroll")}).bind("mouseout",function(){$(this).smoothDivScroll("startAutoScroll")});
$("div#projectenRijDrie").bind("mouseover",function(){$(this).smoothDivScroll("stopAutoScroll")}).bind("mouseout",function(){$(this).smoothDivScroll("startAutoScroll")})
});
```

I tried te following:

```
$(window).load(function() {
var $scrollElement = $("div#projectenRijEen");
$scrollElement.smoothDivScroll({});
$(window).resize(function () {
    $scrollElement.data({
    motherElementOffset: $scrollElement.offset().left
    });
});
});
```

found on http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=241455, but I couldn't get it working

Can somebody please help me how to keep te scroller scrolling when zooming out?

Comment: I've got the same issue, so a solution to this would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware of this problem and have done some tests and tried some tricks to solve it. So far I have made some progress, but it's a tricky problem and I haven't solved the problem yet. This issue is reported on GitHub (https://github.com/tkahn/Smooth-Div-Scroll/issues/2). You can follow the discussion there.